What caused だ to supplant な as the 終止形 of 形容動詞?
The English Wikipedia article for 形容動詞 lists several historical inflections, which explains the peculiarity of な as the 連体形 for 形容動詞. Clearly in earlier stages of Japanese, all forms were primarily based on the verb なり/なる > な, not であり/である > だ. But at some point during the Early Modern Japanese stage, だ started to supplant な almost entirely, only leaving out the 連体形 な and 已然形 なれ. This resulted in a rather weird instance of suppletion, where forms of different words are smashed together into an inflection of a single word.

であら>だろ・であり>だっ・である>だ・な・なれ/なら・✕

(未然形, 連用形 and 終止形 of な were supplanted by だ)
Compare this to an earlier Middle Japanese inflection:

なら・なり・なり>な・なる>な・なれ・✕

What could've caused this shift? And why did only the 連体形 and 已然形 survive into modern Japanese?

For ease of context: the historical forms that Vun-Hugh Vaw describes at WIkipedia are here.

Historical linguistics more often has answers to what, when and where changed, and only rarely has answers to why it changed (maybe outside area of phonology).
